# height issues and responsiveness

Tags: html, css

In this my footer takes and covers my con div an I don't know why.

I need to make this as responsive webpage.

How to achieve that?

I googled and found that most of them are using media queries but I am not able to understand.

If I take footer right:0; then footer disappears completely. Any solution?

```css
body {
    margin: 0 px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100 % ;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 px;
    background - color: orange;
}
#header, #footer {
    width: 100 % ;
    height: 50 px;
    position: fixed;
    background - color: black;
    right: 0 px;
    z - index: 100;
}
#header {
    top: 0;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10 px;
    color: white;
    clear: both;
}

#footer img {
    float: right;
    margin: 5 px;
    padding: 5 px;
}

#navbar {
    height: 60 px;
    width: 100 % ;
    background - color: black;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

}

ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20 px 20 px;
    float: left;
}
ul li a {
    color: white;
}
#navbar a: hover {
    border - bottom: 3 px solid red;
    padding: 19 px;
}
.active {
    background - color: gray;
}

#myCarousel {
 background - color: white;
 height: 370 px;
 width: 100 % ;
 float: left;
}
.carousel - inner > .item > img,
.carousel - inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 70 % ;
    height: 15 % ;
    margin: auto;
    background - color: white;
}



.thumbnail {
    height: 300 px;
    width: 300 px;
    padding: 25 px auto;
    margin: 5 px;

}
#con {
    width: 100 % ;
    height: 300 px;
}
.contact {
    width: 60 % ;
    height: 300 px;
    background - color: grey;
    padding: 100 px 25 px;
    float: left;
}

.enquiry {
    width: 40 % ;
    height: 300 px;
    background - color: seagreen;
    float: left;
    padding - left: 5 px;
}
input[type = text]: focus {
    border: 3 px solid red;
}
input[type = "text"] {
    margin: 0 0 15 px 0;
}
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>student</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <!--start wrapper-->
  <div id="header">
   <!--start header-->
   <div class="navbar">
    <!--start nav-->
    <ul>
     <li><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About us</li>
     <li><a href="services.html">Services</li>
     <li><a href="products.html">Products</li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <!--end nav-->
  </div>
  <!--end header-->
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <!--carasel start-->
   <!-- Indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
   </ol>
   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <!--start carosel inner-->
    <div class="item active">
     <img src="../task/photo/h.jpg" alt="Home">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Home</h3>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
     <img src="../task/photo/as.jpg" alt="About us">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>About us</h3>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
     <img src="../task/photo/s.jpg" alt="Services">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Services</h3>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <img src="../task/photo/p.jpg" alt="Products">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>products</h3>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <img src="../task/photo/c.jpg" alt="Contact us">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Contact us</h3>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!--carosel inner end-->

   <!-- Left and right controls -->
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
  </div>
  <!--end carosel-->
  <div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
   <!--boxes-->
   <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="D:\task\photo\i.jpg" alt="Innovation">
      <p> <strong>Innovation</strong>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="D:\task\photo\cr.png" alt="Creative">
      <p> <strong>Creativity</strong>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="D:\task\photo\po.jpg" alt="Positive">
      <p>
       <strong>Positivity</strong>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!--end boxes-->
   <div id="con">
    <!--start con-->
    <div class="contact">
     <!-- start contact-->
     <h1>Address</h1>
     <p>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
      Abc private limited no54,2ndstreet, madipakkam, chennai-67.
     </p>
     <p>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
      ABCPVT@gmail.com
     </p>
    </div>
    <!--end contact-->
    <div class="enquiry">
     <!--start enquiry-->
     <h1>Enquiry Form</h1>
     <table border="0" align="center">
      <form name="form" action="email.php" id="form" method="post">
       <tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td><input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <<tr>
         <td>Email</td>
         <td><input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Phone</td>
         <td><input name="phone" placeholder="phonenumber" type="text" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Message</td>
         <td><textarea name="msg" placeholder="Type your text here..."></textarea>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input id="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
       </tr>
      </form>
     </table>
    </div>
    <!--end enquiry-->
   </div>
   <!--end con-->
   <div id="footer">
    <!--start footer-->
    copyrights &copy; to WWW.abcpvt.com
    <img src="../task/photo/fb.png" alt="fb" />
    <img src="../task/photo/ln.png" alt="tweet" />
    <img src="../task/photo/tw.png" alt="linkedin" />
   </div>
   <!--end footer-->
  </div>
  <!--end wrapper-->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Increase the #con's bottom padding.

Comment: no change footer is not visible

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) you can learn the most basic skill of the Internet communication.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it into the column structure that you're using with bootstrap, the bootstrap framework you are using is fully responsive please see http://getbootstrap.com and look at their tuts

Answer (score 0):

This will do,

Add the following css element:

```
#footer{
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: yea i can see the footer but its width is not 100% how do i resolve it.

Comment: Either custom set the width or take any footer from bootstrap site and customize it so the footer will be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootstrap but you are not using the classes that comes with it. You do not need those many css and you can still have a responsive webpage in no time. Please follow this tutorial on bootstrap: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Hope this helps,

Thanks

Comment: don wanna use bootstrap need to know by html and css itself.yea i have gone through those tutorials

Comment: just add 3 <br/> tags after the #con and you should be able to get the footer right. Let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think all you're needing is `padding: 50px 0` for the `body` tag. Let me know if you're looking for something different.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: orange;
}

#header,
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#header {
  top: 0;
}

#footer {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
}

#footer img {
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#navbar {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20 px 20 px;
  float: left;
}

ul li a {
  color: white;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  padding: 19px;
}

.active {
  background-color: gray;
}

#myCarousel {
  background-color: white;
  height: 370px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 15%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.thumbnail {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 25px auto;
  margin: 5px;
}

#con {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.contact {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 100px 25px;
  float: left;
}

.enquiry {
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: seagreen;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
 <title>student</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <!--start wrapper-->
  <div id="header">
   <!--start header-->
   <div class="navbar">
    <!--start nav-->
    <ul>
     <li><a class="active" href="home.html">Home</li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About us</li>
     <li><a href="services.html">Services</li>
     <li><a href="products.html">Products</li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <!--end nav-->
  </div>
  <!--end header-->
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <!--carasel start-->
   <!-- Indicators -->
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
   </ol>
   <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <!--start carosel inner-->
    <div class="item active">
     <img src="../task/photo/h.jpg" alt="Home">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Home</h3>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
     <img src="../task/photo/as.jpg" alt="About us">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>About us</h3>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
     <img src="../task/photo/s.jpg" alt="Services">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Services</h3>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <img src="../task/photo/p.jpg" alt="Products">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>products</h3>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <img src="../task/photo/c.jpg" alt="Contact us">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Contact us</h3>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!--carosel inner end-->

   <!-- Left and right controls -->
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
  </div>
  <!--end carosel-->
  <div class="container-fluid text-center bg-grey">
   <!--boxes-->
   <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="D:\task\photo\i.jpg" alt="Innovation">
      <p> <strong>Innovation</strong>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="D:\task\photo\cr.png" alt="Creative">
      <p> <strong>Creativity</strong>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="D:\task\photo\po.jpg" alt="Positive">
      <p>
       <strong>Positivity</strong>
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!--end boxes-->
   <div id="con">
    <!--start con-->
    <div class="contact">
     <!-- start contact-->
     <h1>Address</h1>
     <p>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
      Abc private limited no54,2ndstreet, madipakkam, chennai-67.
     </p>
     <p>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
      ABCPVT@gmail.com
     </p>
    </div>
    <!--end contact-->
    <div class="enquiry">
     <!--start enquiry-->
     <h1>Enquiry Form</h1>
     <table border="0" align="center">
      <form name="form" action="email.php" id="form" method="post">
       <tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Name</td>
         <td><input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <<tr>
         <td>Email</td>
         <td><input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Phone</td>
         <td><input name="phone" placeholder="phonenumber" type="text" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Message</td>
         <td><textarea name="msg" placeholder="Type your text here..."></textarea>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input id="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
       </tr>
      </form>
     </table>
    </div>
    <!--end enquiry-->
   </div>
   <!--end con-->
   <div id="footer">
    <!--start footer-->
    copyrights &copy; to WWW.abcpvt.com
    <img src="../task/photo/fb.png" alt="fb" />
    <img src="../task/photo/ln.png" alt="tweet" />
    <img src="../task/photo/tw.png" alt="linkedin" />
   </div>
   <!--end footer-->
  </div>
  <!--end wrapper-->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```